# Second position of array of structures has garbage

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've been trying to wrap my head around arrays of structs in C, but can't seem to figure this out. I've done research and searched on SO but I can't find the answer to the following problem:

I created a vector that holds a list of items, it's size and it's maxsize, so that I can use it as a dynamic array.

When I insert my second item on this vector, it prints out garbage. The first, third and forth items, however, appear as they should. Why would this be?

Here's my code.
library.c:

```
#include "library.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    vector *catalog = init(2);

    Book a = {
        .title = "TestA", .isbn13 = "12345678901", .authors = "AuthorA", .publisher = "publisherA", .year = 1999
    }, b = {
        .title = "TestB", .isbn13 = "12345678901", .authors = "AuthorB", .publisher = "publisherB", .year = 1999
    }, c = {
        .title = "TestC", .isbn13 = "12345678901", .authors = "AuthorC", .publisher = "publisherC", .year = 1999
    }, d = {
        .title = "TestD", .isbn13 = "12345678901", .authors = "AuthorD", .publisher = "publisherD", .year = 1999
    };

    add(catalog, a);
    add(catalog, b);
    add(catalog, c);
    add(catalog, d);

    printCatalog(catalog);

    destroy(catalog);

    return 0;
}
```

library.h:

```
#ifndef library_h
#define library_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ISBN13_SIZE 14

typedef struct {
    char *title;
    char isbn13[ISBN13_SIZE];
    char *authors;
    char *publisher;
    int year;
} Book;

typedef Book type_t;

typedef struct {
    type_t *li;
    size_t length;
    size_t maxLength;
} vector;

/* libgest header */
vector *init(size_t initial_size);
int grow(vector *v);
type_t add(vector *v, type_t value);
void destroy(vector *v);
void printCatalog(vector *v);
void printBook(type_t b);

#endif
```

libgest.c:

```
#include "library.h"

vector *init(size_t initial_size) {
    vector *v = malloc(sizeof(vector));
    v->li = malloc(sizeof(type_t) * initial_size);
    v->length = 0;
    v->maxLength = initial_size;
    return v;
}

int grow(vector *v) {
    type_t *newli = malloc(2*v->maxLength); /* Allocate list with double size */
    if(newli == NULL)
        return 0; /* Failed to allocate memory */
    memcpy(newli, v->li, sizeof(vector) * v->length); /* Copy contents over to the new list */
    free(v->li); /* Free old list memory to avoid memory leaks */
    v->li = newli; /* Set our list to the new, expanded, list */
    v->maxLength *= 2; /* Update vector's max size */
    return 1; /* Success */
}

type_t add(vector *v, type_t value) {
    if(v->length > v->maxLength-1)
        grow(v);
    v->li[v->length++] = value;
    return value;
}

void destroy(vector *v) {
    free(v->li);
    free(v);
}

void printCatalog(vector *v) {
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < v->length; i++) {
        printBook(v->li[i]);
    }
}

void printBook(type_t b) {
    printf("Title: %s\n", b.title);
    printf("ISBN: %s\n\n", b.isbn13);
}
```

When I run it, it prints:

```
Title: TitleA
ISBN: 12345678901

Title: x12
ISBN: b

Title: TitleC
ISBN: 12345678901

Title: TitleD
ISBN: 12345678901
```

So why would the second element in the vector be garbage?

Comment: On my platform your program crashes somewhere deep in `free` and this means to 99% that you have overwritten memory that doesn't belong to you somewhere in your code or you did some other nasty thing.

Comment: If I use `vector *catalog = init(7);` it seems to work which is a strong indicator that the problem is in the `grow` function, because in that case `grow` is never called.

Comment: Anticipating your next question: _Why is only the second element printed incorrectly, but the other elements are printed correctly?_. Answer: google "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Yes and I just found out that I was getting correctly printed C and D items because of the previously written default memory that was there, but the dynamic memory allocation was off. Fixed now :) Thanks @Jabberwocky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `grow` method you want to increase size of `li` array twice but malloc takes parameter in bytes so factor - `sizeof(type_t)` is missing, add it and replace below line

```
type_t *newli = malloc(2*v->maxLength);
```

by

```
type_t *newli = malloc(2 * v->maxLength * sizeof(type_t));
```

Another issue is in `memcpy` function, you want to copy all `type_t` items not vector items, replace

```
memcpy(newli, v->li, sizeof(vector) * v->length);
```

by

```
memcpy(newli, v->li, sizeof(type_t) * v->length);
```

Comment: The malloc() was a dumb mistake, but the memcpy() error would be hard for me to catch. Thanks @rafix07!